# Does Google Nearby use GPS?

Tags: android, gps, google-nearby

I can't seem to find the answer to that question. The nearby API uses Bluetooth, sound, and Eddystone beacons. Does it also use GPS presently?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Nearby developers website:

> Nearby uses a combination of Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy, Wi-Fi and near-ultrasonic audio to communicate a unique-in-time pairing code between devices.

However, latitude and longitude may be provided when registering a beacon.

See: https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview